How to export multiple tables resulting from the tab command in Stata to LaTeX
I have sorted and would like to export the tables resulting from this command by state3 year: tab cooking_scorein Stata to LaTeX.
I tried to use esttab, cells("Freq." "Percent") collabels("Freq." "Percent") noobs nonumber nomtitle label tex and  tabout state3 year cooking_score using test1.tex to export it but it is not giving me the output that I would like to have in LaTeX.
It is giving me a tabulated table of the cooking score by state but not a tabulated table of the cooking score by state and year. For example, I want to see the breakdown of the cooking score in each state by year.

not giving me?

Sorry, I meant it is giving me a tabulated table of the cooking score by state but not a tabulated table of the cooking score by state and year. For example, I want to see the breakdown of the cooking score in each state by year.

Text still reads but it is giving me the output that I would like to have in LaTeX. Please correct your text; otherwise I will have to regard this as unclear.
